# java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin

I have a folder of images inside my resources folder. I am using them to run some unit tests to obtain some metrics. So the folder path is something like this: $root/android/app/test/resources/images/$image

I am trying to create a bitmap from this image by passing the path like this:

```
 val bitmap: Bitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.fullPath);
```

However, when i run the tests, I get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!

    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:27)
```

What is this error and how can it be fixed?

Comment: BitmapFactory.decodeFile is a static method, unavailble in the unit test. You are gonna have to mock it in some way.

Comment: Please how can I mock it? Any resource?